# vmware host stuck after adding a virtual drive to client

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi, iscsi

I use ESXi 5.0

I created a virtual (400GB) drive (located on an iSCSI mapped drive), and tried to add it to a specific client on the host.
The task has stopped at 11%. After over an hour, it seems that everything is pretty stuck.

**EDIT:** I found that the iSCSI was defined as Thin provision on the NAS (QNAP) - could that cause the original problem where the creation got stuck?

Looking at the datastore - it says that 400GB are allocated, but I don't see the new drive with the client.

[image]

Browsing the DS - I see the client name, and inside the vmdk file

[image]

- I tried to add the vmdk again, using the add exisiting hardware - but I don't see the vmdk

[image]

- One error that I get, trying to work with the host is:

  Call "HostAutoStartManager.Reconfigure" for object "autoStartManager-9" on vCenter Server "localhost" failed.
- I keep getting an error: Another Task is already in progress.  - is it possible to stop that task? how do I track it?

How can I check if the process is still working? or should I restart the host and pray for good?